# Transform a Scala Sequence in Pairs

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a sequence like this:

```
val l = Seq(1,2,3,4)
```

which I want to transform to `List(Seq(1,2), Seq(2,3), Seq(3,4))`

Here is what I tried:

```
def getPairs(inter: Seq[(Int, Int)]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = l match {
 case Nil => inter
 case x :: xs => getPairs(inter :+ (x, xs.head))
}
```

This strangely seems not to work? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for comprehension, for instance as follows,

```
for ( (a,b) <- l zip l.drop(1) ) yield Seq(a,b)
```

Note `l.drop(1)` (in contrast to `l.tail`) will deliver an empty list if `l` is empty or has at most one item.

Answer (score 9):

You can also **just use [`sliding`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@sliding%28size:Int,step:Int%29:Iterator[Repr]):**

```
l.sliding(2).toList
res1: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4))
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I got to know about the zip method:

```
xs zip xs.tail
```

Comment: `tail` throws an exception if `xs` is empty. `xs zip xs.drop(1)` works, though.

Answer (score 1):

The already given answers describe well, how to do this in a scala way.
However, you might also want an explanation why your code does not work, so here it comes:

Your `getPairs` function expects a list of tuples as input and returns a list of tuples. But you say you want to transform a list of single values into a list to tuples. So if you call `getPairs(l)` you will get a `type mismatch` compiler error.

You would have to refactor your code to take a simple list:

```
def pairs(in: Seq[Int]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
  @tailrec
  def recursive(remaining: Seq[Int], result: Seq[(Int, Int)]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
    remaining match {
      case Nil => result
      case last +: Nil => result
      case head +: next +: tail => recursive(next +: tail, (head, next) +: result)
    }
  }

  recursive(in, Nil).reverse
}
```

and from here it's a small step to a generic function:

```
def pairs2[A](in: Seq[A]): Seq[(A, A)] = {
  @tailrec
  def recursive(remaining: Seq[A], result: Seq[(A, A)]): Seq[(A, A)] = {
    remaining match {
      case Nil => result
      case last +: Nil => result
      case head +: next +: tail => recursive(next +: tail, (head, next) +: result)
    }
  }

  recursive(in, Nil).reverse
}
```